# PHP - Replace character in PhpStorm

Tags: php, arrays, regex, replace, phpstorm

I have a small request.

On my application, written in PHP 5.3, the PHP is written like that for array:

```php
$customer[name] = 'Joe';
$customer[city] = 'New York';
```

At the moment, I'm working on PHP upgrading. The goal is to be compatible with PHP 8.1 FPM.

The error is written in the log:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "name" in ****/customer.php:13
```

I need to add the quotes in the array index, as in this example :

```php
$customer['name'] = 'Joe';
$customer['city'] = 'New York';
```

How can I add the quotes automatically with PhpStorm?

I'm not able to use the function `Find / Replace` from PhpStorm to do the job. I was able to find the right data with the regex `\[[a-z]*\]`. But I am not able to replace data with the regex.

Comment: `$customer[name] = 'Joe';` would never have worked

Comment: This would have thrown a notice in every PHP version but 8+ changed to an error, https://3v4l.org/oiYWp.

Comment: It would have worked, but it would have thrown warnings before 8. `Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`. The warnings could have been suppressed or ignored, so the OP Never realized it.

Comment: Ok @aynber I guess it depends upon your definition of "Works" :) I guess its... code still runs but gets the wrong results

Comment: Just for your own sanity's sake you are hopefully upgrading to 7.x first because 8.x removed deprecated things so you might miss out on warnings.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for your advice. In fact, this application has legacy php code. It was developed in 2003 by a trainee. So. all the bad things from programming are in this application. I adviced my management to keep a CRM from the market. It would be the best solution. But they'd prefer to stay with this ugly app....

Comment: Funny thing is my company claims to be GDRP (I'm based in UE) compatible.  Application is running on Ubuntu 12, PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.5 and database model looks like Excel rather than relational database model. Of course, there is no unit test in the code and it's impossible to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do want regex. You want to use to use parentheses to grab the word inside the brackets, then use `$1` to replace it:

Find: `\[(\w+)\]`

Replace: `['$1']`

Comment: ( could add `[$][a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*` to ensure variable as well, `[$][a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*\[(\w+)\]`)